# How can access formulas as I process it with Matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, formulas

I load an xls file in Matlab, and I need not only the numeric values but the formulas also. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You only need the numeric values, and the formulas ?! That practically makes the whole of .xls file.

Comment: Yes, numeric values, and formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this submission on File Exchange:
[AnalyseExcelFormulas](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9629-analyseexcelformulas)

Comment: I get an error. I think, it work only in Windows, and not on Mac. >> AnalyseExcelFormulas('ADYAN.xls') ??? Undefined function or method 'actxserver' for input arguments of type 'char'. Error in ==> AnalyseExcelFormulas at 90 h.activex1 = actxserver('Excel.Application'); –

Comment: You are right. It's using COM, which is available only on Windows, to access Excel files. But you didn't specify the OS in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a formula from the data values in the xls file, perhaps
the [Curve Fitting Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/curvefitting/) is what you need.